# Setting the outer class field in an asynchronous class

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am trying to set a field from the outer class within an asynchronous class but it is not working for me.

```
public class FlinkJsonObject {

    TrafficData jsonObject;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public FlinkJsonObject(String url, int port) throws URISyntaxException {
        final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("wss://city.up.us/outbound/SPPAnalyticsStatement"));

        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(new WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(String message) {
                try {
                    // Using this does not work here
                    this.jsonObject = mapper.readValue(message, TrafficData.class);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FlinkJsonObject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I have tried setting the field using an external method and calling it in the asynchronous class but it does not work for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work for me"?

Comment: Using 'this' keyword within the asynchronous class gives a compile time error and I want to set the jsonObject field with the data which is coming from the web socket handler.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Have you tried `FlinkJsonObject.this.jsonObject` or simply `jsonObject`?

Comment: I tried doing both but unfortunately its being set to null for some reason. I am relatively naive to asynchronous programming so I was wondering if there is any other way to handle this.

Comment: Well, "being set to null" is quite different from a "compile time error". Have a look at the return value of `readValue`, that's probably `null`.